# Excel TEXT function - Number Positioning

Tags: excel, text, concatenation

I'm calculating the difference between 2 columns of data and calculating the numeric difference and % increase. I wanted to combine these two values in one cell using the text function.

The problem: I have successfully done this in excel but have a formatting problem. I have separated the numeric and percent difference by the delimiter "|". Sometimes the % difference value is two digits and some times its 1 digit. I'd like to have a placeholder for the tens digit so all of the delimiters align in the column. Is there any way to do this using the function?

For example, you could solve this problem by adding "000" in the format_text argument for the second text function, but I don't want any leading zeros in my display cell.

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` to add leading or trailing space:

```
= H70-F70 & Text(H70/F70-1, " | ??%")
```

You can also use Monospaced font like Courier New for better alignment.